# Amazon Sagemaker- Integrating Model Registry with the Model created by Processing Job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I am created a pipeline for ML Ops where i train a model and place the Model in S3 bucket.
I have also created a processing job that registers the model to sagemaker Model registry. The problem i am facing is that even though i have the model quality metrics i am not able to integrate it with the Model Registry when i register the model.

I have a json file which contains model metrics in format:

```
{"mae":<value>, ...}
```

I am passing this json's S3URI as model metrics parameter in create_model_package. Is there any issue with the format i am using?
I am following
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-monitor-model-quality-metrics.html as reference for the json format.
But when I look for model metrics in the model registry in sagemaker studio it fails to load it. I am not able to find anything about the required format so that i can use my own custom generated metric to be displayed on sagemaker studio.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are following the format correctly, as described on the page you linked? For example, the metrics should follow the following JSON format:

```
evaluation_report = {
    "metrics": {
        "metric_1_name": {"value": 0.5, "standard_deviation": 0.5},
        "metric_2_name": {"value": 0.5, "standard_deviation": "NaN"},
    }
}
```

The format that you seem to describe it would not be correct, you need the keys "value" and "standard_deviation" for each metric, which can have any name you want. The top-level key (in the above case "metrics") should not matter.

Note that the standard deviation value can be "NaN", e.g. for classification metrics.